# Why there is no use changing /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, networking, dns, hosts

Here are the commands:

```
[17:31:13 root etc]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.2   myweb.com
[17:31:25 root etc]# ping myweb.com
PING myweb.com (184.154.233.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ns1.siteground278.com (184.154.233.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=275 ms
64 bytes from ns1.siteground278.com (184.154.233.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=273 ms
64 bytes from ns1.siteground278.com (184.154.233.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=281 ms
^C
--- myweb.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 273.625/276.874/281.478/3.346 ms
```

pinging myweb.com on a machine without networkmanager will get 127.0.0.2, but I am not sure, anyone got an idea what is this about?

I am using fedora 20.

Comment: Likely, `myweb.com` was already in the resolver client's cache.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Most Linux distributions by default have resolver cache disabled. Also, hosts file should take priority nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check configuration in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and look for `hosts`:

```
hosts:      files dns
```

Does it look like that? Basically this line tells the system how to resolve host names: by default on my RHELs it's hostnames first than DNS servers.

Do you cache DNS? Usually Linuxes have [nscd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd) (daemon to cache DNSes) disabled by default.
Anyway, hosts if configured right should always take priority over DNS.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, but who cleared nsswitch.conf? I saw there are contents in others' machines? Do you have an idea.

Comment: It would be impossible for us to guess who has cleared `nsswitch.conf` for you. I'm guessing that your distro is still using this file? I'm not very familiar with the latest Fedora.